# Django ORM: Chaining aggregated querysets into one

Tags: django, orm, aggregate, chaining, django-queryset

Can I chain these two querysets into one?

```
qs1 = OrderTicket.objects.filter(date__gt=datetime.date(2009, 1, 1), date__lt=datetime.date(2009, 1, 30)).values('order_type').annotate(value_1 = Sum('gbp_value')).order_by('order_type'),
qs2 = OrderTicket.objects.filter(date__gt=datetime.date(2009, 2, 1), date__lt=datetime.date(2009, 2, 30)).values('order_type').annotate(value_2 = Sum('gbp_value')).order_by('order_type'),
```

All I want is the value_1 and value_2 columns. Q objects are not what I need. Maybe the ORM does not support this.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine querysets using the | and & operators:

```
# You can combine queries with & and |.
>>> s1 = Article.objects.filter(id__exact=1)
>>> s2 = Article.objects.filter(id__exact=2)
>>> s1 | s2
[<Article: Area woman programs in Python>, <Article: Second article>]
>>> s1 & s2
[]
```

Source http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/basic/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Q objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to replace your filter for date__gt and date__lt

Example (not tested):

```
qs1 = OrderTicket.objects
    .filter(  Q(date__gt=datetime.date(2009, 1, 1), date__lt=datetime.date(2009, 1, 30)) 
            | Q(date__gt=datetime.date(2009, 2, 1), date__lt=datetime.date(2009, 2, 30))
           )
    .values('order_type').annotate(value_1 = Sum('gbp_value')).order_by('order_type')
```

This should return both the dates you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Tom but that is not what I am looking for. value_1 and value_2 sums all gbp_values per their respective month. How can I chain those two aggregate querysets?